# How to write testcase for [object NodeList] in jasmine testing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, testcase, nodelist

When I try write this testcase.

```
 let abc = document.querySelectorAll("span");
 expect(abc).toBe(true);
```

I'm getting

> Expected **[object NodeList]** to be **true.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a nodelist does not take on a bool value so that test will fail. Instead check that the list is not null ( empty ).

```
expect(abc).not.toBeNull()
```